# Queries for Importing Data from Flat-File Tables to Many-to-Many Relationship

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I can't figure out how to generate the required queries in Access to import data from flat-file text pages.

The sample data below shows the 2 types of tables I have - one with file data, and one with persons data, where multiple people can be related to multiple files, and multiple files can be related to multiple people.

Table 1: File Data

```
    FileID  Month    Day  Synopsis
    1234    January  22   Example
    1235    January  23   Example
    1236    January  24   Example
    1237    January  25   Example
```

Table 2: Person Data

```
 FileID    Surname   GivenOne
 1234      SMITH     Jane
 1234      SMITH     John
 1235      DOE       John
 1236      DOE       Jane
 1237      SMITH     Jane
```

What I want is to create append queries that adds new files to an existing table of files, adds new persons to an existing master table for all persons (that contains only one record for each person and contains an auto-generated PersonID for each person record), and *appends the link table to account for any new files a person record may be associated to.*

Does anyone have any suggestions for how to do this?  I understand using link/join tables to link PersonID to FileID, but I can't figure out how to deal with appending new information to existing tables, given the many-to-many relationship.  This will be a task I'll be repeating daily, so I'll want queries that I can repeatedly run.  Any tips/suggestions very much appreciated.

Comment: 1. I think you're going to need some VBA for this. -- 2. Is there a field (or a combination of fields) to **uniquely identify** a person? Because first+last name isn't going to be enough (John Smith etc...)

Comment: 1. Agh - was hoping I would be able to avoid VBA.  Any suggestions on how to write the code I would need?  2. I also have a field with DOB (didn't include in my example) - was hoping to use the combination of surname, given one, & DOB to uniquely ID a person (there is almost 0 chance in our system that any two people would have matching DOBs, surnames, & first names).

Comment: (To add a bit more context, after some more Googling/reviewing threads on StackOverflow, I think what I am trying to do is create queries that will essentially append normalized tables from un-normalized tables, accounting for the many-to-many relationship).